# codeigniter - jquery pop up error message

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, message

Hello i want to show a jquery popup with some error message in, but i dont know how to work it out with codeigniter,

i have this in my function if the username or password is wrong

$this->session->set_flashdata('flash_loginFejl', 'Brugernavn eller password er forkert');
$data['content'] = 'popup_view';
$this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

put it shows up like this:

http://d.pr/w2zT

what im doing wrong ?

Comment: Your question is missing your javascript (i.e How are you getting the contents of the jquery UI dialog box) and also the code for your template. It would help to work out the solution if you posted this too (the relevant parts)

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my header file that I include on all my pages:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/black-tie/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

My template file:

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header') ?>

<?php $this->load->view($content) ?>

<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer') ?>
```